# Permission denied while playing mediaFile

Tags: android

This is my playButton that was supposed to play recorded file.

```
 playButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        String main_path = c.getFilesDir().getPath();
                        String appended_path = main_path+"/recordings";
                        String newSource =  appended_path+"/"+source;
                        Log.e("Source File", newSource);
                        String fixedUrl = newSource.replaceAll("\\s", "%20");
                        playFile(fixedUrl);
                    }
                });
```

The file name has special characters (space) like this. and i escaped it as shown in fixedUrl (String) above. 
But, it is not working well. Suppose for file that is named " record.3gp " plays smoothly, while file that is named " 2018:11:06 18:16:12.3gp" cannot be played as it says:

```
Failed to open file '/data/user/0/com.utilnepal/files/recordings/2018:11:06%2018:12:53.3gp'. (Permission denied)
```

Any idea how to solve this? 
Here is the play method

```
       private void playFile(String source, final RecordingViewHolder recordingViewHolder) {
//            getPermission();
            mPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
            try {
                mPlayer.setDataSource(source);
                mPlayer.prepare();
                mPlayer.start();
//               

            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e("Error Occured", "prepare() failed " +e.getMessage());
                Toast.makeText(c,"Cannot Play File",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                togglePause(recordingViewHolder);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Post your code about method `playFile` and full error stack

Comment: A filename might not contain one of the following characters: \ / : * ? " < > | so try to see if it works without ":" in file name, or without spaces and spot which one causes the error.